# Best way to write a reusable module with URLs?

Tags: php

I am writing a reusable module in PHP.  This module can write content to an arbitrary page, but it needs URLs that reference scripts within this module.  Right now, I use a hard-coded variable that points to the root of the module:

```
$module_root = "http://www.example.com/my_module/";
```

Is there a way to determine the root URL of my module dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

**1. URI oriented**

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

In your case it should contain:

```
/my_module/
```

So using:

```
$parts = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

you will have your root module name in $parts[1] variable.

**2. Filesystem oriented**

you may use filesystem paths to determine where you are, i.e.
moduleMain.php

```
$module_root = dirname( __FILE__ );
```

submodule/pluginMain.php

```
$submodule = mb_substr( dirname( __FILE__ ), mb_strlen($module_root) );
```

(assuming that you have $module_root variable available)

Comment: This module is included in other PHP scripts outside the module.  Thus, it displays the URI to the arbitrary (including) script, even if I call the variable within my module (the included script).

Comment: you may use filesystem paths to determine where you are, i.e.
moduleMain.php
$module_root = dirname( __FILE__ );

submodule/pluginMain.php
$submodule = mb_substr( dirname( __FILE__ ), mb_strlen($module_root) );

(assuming that you have $module_root variable available)

Comment: For (2), dirname( __FILE__ ) is showing "C:\Documents and Settings\...".  How do I get the URL version of $module_root?